# How do you get view caching to work on a per-action basis in the PagesController

Tags: cakephp, caching, cakephp-2.0

I've set up view caching successfully for other controller/actions in my Cake application.  But PagesController does not seem to cache anything at all.

At the top of PagesController.php I have:

```
var $cacheAction = array (
     'display/index/' => array('callbacks' => false, 'duration' => '+1 week'),
     'index' => array('callbacks' => false, 'duration' => '+1 week'),
     '/' => array('callbacks' => false, 'duration' => '+1 week'),

);
```

But still, when I visit the homepage either through '/' or '/pages/index/' -- nothing caches.

Does the PagesController follow different rules than other controllers when it comes to view caching?  I am at a loss...

Answer (score 0):

Though it will cache everything from the PagesController, this works for me (placed before the `display()` method):

```
public $cacheAction = '1 week';
```

EDIT: this works as well when used in the `display()` method:

```
$this->cacheAction = '1 week';
```

Comment: Yeah, I need the caching on a per-action basis.